# Label function used to map to a facet grid in seaborn

Tags: python, function, seaborn

I have been playing around with [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html) plotting example in Seaborn.

However, I am a little confused with the label plotting function:

```
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "x")
```

I assume that the facet grid map function (`g.map`) calls the label function with argument x. However, within the function, x is not used, only `label`. How does the function know what the other arguments are if they are not passed by the map function?

I am clearly missing something, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer? I can give more explanation if needed

Comment: I have. Still a little confused to be honest.

Comment: Perhaps I can clarify: what is the confusion?

Comment: I am just confused about how the function knows where to take the label values from. Is it because it is the only object column in df? I have tried to plot my own data using this code, and it plotted the same value for each row which is why I tried to add the label column to the function call.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an explanation of where the `label` argument comes from. Let me know if it is still unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) definition of [`map`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/065d3c1ed58b029d61913cca8fc315cc985ffc91/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L692) the call signature of `FacetGrid.map` is

```py
def map(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    """ 
    ...
    args : strings
            Column names in self.data that identify variables with data to
            plot. The data for each variable is passed to `func` in the
            order the variables are specified in the call.
    ... 
    """
```

So assuming `g` is of type `seaborn.FacetGrid` - which we confirm with the line

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)
```

in the [linked example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)

Then when you call

```py
g.map(label, "x")
```

`"x"` is interpreted as a column in `self.data` (`df["x"]` in this case). Whether this data is used in the function or not is irrelevant: its presence is mandated by the call signature.

---

#### Edit

The values which are passed to the `label` argument of the `func` in `g.map` come from this portion of the [source](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/065d3c1ed58b029d61913cca8fc315cc985ffc91/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L754):

```py
def map(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    # Insert a label in the keyword arguments for the legend
    if self._hue_var is not None:
        kwargs["label"] = utils.to_utf8(self.hue_names[hue_k])
    # ...
```

Basically this gets the `hue` name from each `datasubset` and passes it to the `label` keyword argument which is then passed into the drawing function:

```py
    # ...
    # Draw the plot
    self._facet_plot(func, ax, plot_args, kwargs)
    # ...
```

where the function, `func`, passed into `g.map` is finally [called](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/065d3c1ed58b029d61913cca8fc315cc985ffc91/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L852)

```py
def _facet_plot(self, func, ax, plot_args, plot_kwargs):
    # ...
    func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)
    # ...
```

So the `label` argument comes from specifying `df["g"]` as the `hue` argument in the line

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)
```